# How come Xcode can't automatically link against modules where only a category is referenced?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, llvm

I have module that contains a single class and a category on UIImageView which uses that class. For some reason Xcode cannot automatically link against the module if I only ever reference the category in my code.

For example, I have a category on UIImageView that defines the method setImageWithURL:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
[imageView setImageWithURL: [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.something.com/image.jpg"];
```

will crash with a "unrecognized selector sent to instance" but

```
FDImageLoader *completelyUselessReference = [FDImageLoader sharedInstance];

UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
[imageView setImageWithURL: [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.something.com/image.jpg"];
```

will work just fine.

You can see this in Xcode if you clone my module, https://github.com/reidmain/FDImageLoader, and open up the example iOS project. In the app delegate I have a pointless reference to FDImageLoader but if you copy and paste the code above into the app delegate you can see the crash.

The interesting thing is that if I go to the build phases of my target and add FDImageLoader to the "Link Binary With Libraries" section then both examples above work fine. Xcode seems to do some sort of magic and if it doesn't see any classes referenced inside a module it will just completely omit the module even if category in it are referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using -ObjC linker flag.

> Passing the -ObjC option to the linker causes it to load all members
>   of static libraries that implement any Objective-C class or category.
>   This will pickup any category method implementations. But it can make
>   the resulting executable larger, and may pickup unnecessary objects.
>   For this reason it is not on by default.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html

Comment: -ObjC and -all_load apparently only work after the library/framework has been linked. The issue I am having is that Xcode is not automatically linking the module because I only appear to be referencing categories not classes. If you look at my example project you will see that I already have -ObjC added.